# How do i release my C# winform program with LocalDB 2016 only?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, winforms, localdb

This is awful i had local db 2012 version and i just put the msi with the installer and it worked perfectly. I for some reason upgrade the database and my localdb to 2016 now and i dont know how to get the user to install localdb 2016.

I cant find the MSI for local db 2016 anywhere neither would i link them the express 2016 website which takes ages to install the sql express and then on top of that they have to select the local db version its way too much any help would be awesome! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so you have to locate the MSI after installing local express with localdb option selected thereafter if you have advanced installer or even installshield you can make sure the user install thats msi before installing your program.